# Queue for storing struct objects

Tags: c++, queue

So basically I have a point struct

```
typedef struct point {
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;
} Point;
```

now I want to make a queue for storing points.

```
queue<Point> *pointsQueue = new queue<Point>; // shouldn't be changed
```

However now when I try to push a point into the queue, the following error appears

```
error:request for member 'push' in 'pointQueue', which is of non-class type 'std::queue<Point>*'
```

basically am creating a Point p

```
Point p;
p.x = 3;
p.y = 4;
```

then I push it into the queue

```
pointQueue.push(p);
```

and I have as an include file:

```
#include <queue>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pointQueue` is a pointer, and you are treating like an object. Since there seems to be no reason for it to be a pointer, the simplest solution is to use an object:

```
std::queue<Point> pointsQueue;
```

If you really really need a pointer, then you need to access its member via the `->` operator:

```
pointQueue->push(p);
```

Alternatively, you can de-reference the pointer with the `*` operator. This gives you a reference to the object it points to:

```
(*pointQueue).push(p);
```

As an aside, the `typedef` syntax for declaring types is not necessary in C++, in fact it looks quite strange. This is the usual approach:

```
struct Point 
{
  unsigned int x;
  unsigned int y;
};
```

Comment: There may or may not be a reason for heap allocation. We don't really know without the code. But one of those two cases will cover it!

Comment: A new error appeared: conversion from 'std::queue<point>*' to non scalar type 'std::queue<point>' requested

Comment: @thirdage you are trying to use a pointer as an object somewhere else.

Comment: It was given as : queue<Point> *pointsQueue = new queue<Point>; so i really shouldn't change it.

Comment: @thirdage fine, then use `->` or `*` as shown. Sometimes there really are reasons to use pointers, but quite often this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pointer to a `queue`, not a `queue`. Either use `->` to access members, or remove the indirection.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pointer to variable. Therefore before usage of queue you should get a queue itself. Like this:

```
(*pointQueue).push(p);
```

or shorter, but the same:

```
pointQueue->push(p);
```